# obtaining oauth_verifier from callback

Tags: c#, oauth, verification

I have searched high and low for an answer to this problem. Basically, I am creating a C# application which (In it's first incarnation) will authenticate with the Projectplace API which uses OAuth 1.0a. It currently returns the oauth_verifier to the address bar, but when I use the `var response = request.GetResponse();` method, it returns the `oauth_token` and `oauth token_secret` which I sent as part of the authorization in the first place.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the way this process is supposed to work, but I've read every single answer out there and none seem to address this question. Do you have to, or is it possible, to pull the verifier code from the address bar (or wherever else it can be obtained), after I have entered my username and password on the authentication page after callback URL is loaded?

I believe OAuth1.0a requires the verification code to retrieve an access token, and I cannot find a simple way to pull the verification code.

I would really appreciate any help, it's driving me nuts!!

UPDATED 03.12.12

Thanks for your response!

Essentially, I am the client attempting to retrieve the oauth_verifier from the oauth provider after sending this initial request below, my next step is to authorize then retrieve verifier. I tried the following, hopefully as you suggested, like swimming in the deep end here :)

```
//Generate string for initiation request.
 requestUri.AppendFormat("?oauth_consumer_key={0}&", consumerKey);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce={0}&", nonce);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timeStamp);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0}&", "HMAC-SHA1");
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_version={0}&", "1.0");
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0}", signature);
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestUri.ToString()));
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
 var response = request.GetResponse();
 var queryString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
 var parts = queryString.Split('&');
 var token = parts[1].Substring(parts[1].IndexOf('=') + 1);
 var tokenSecret = parts[0].Substring(parts[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);
 var queryString2 = String.Format("oauth_token={0}", token);

//AUTHORIZE WITH CREDENTIALS FROM USER.
 var authorizeUrl = "https://api.projectplace.com/authorize?" + queryString;
 Process.Start(authorizeUrl);`

//TRY AND READ VERIFICATION STRING AFTER AUTHORIZATION REDIRECT`
 String oauthVerifier = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];
```

Unfortunately, once i've done this, I can't seem to get a querystring returned showing the oauth_verifier that I am clearly seeing in the string showing in the address bar. (Yes it's a very newbish way of describing it, i'm learning the code as well as OAuth :P).

Thanks for your help so far. I tried to run the above, but it just said that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Also, if I attempt to use the previous code I used to obtain the querystring / response? from the initiation request using the following lines, the querystring3 just comes back as blank... really frustrating! :)

`var queryString3 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`
`var parts3 = queryString3.Split('&');`

Comment: When you say "In the address bar" do you mean that it is a query string parameter (e.g. http://yoursite.com?oauth_verifier=<value>)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by "in the address bar" you mean that the oauth_verifier is passed to your site from the ProjectPlace server via a query string parameter in the redirect URL.  In order to read this in your C# server side code, you would use something like the following (I modified your sample code for this solution):

```
 requestUri.AppendFormat("?oauth_consumer_key={0}&", consumerKey);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce={0}&", nonce);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timeStamp);
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0}&", "HMAC-SHA1");
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_version={0}&", "1.0");
 requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0}", signature);
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestUri.ToString()));

 //Note: this is unnecessary - GET is the default
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; 
 //By casting to HttpWebResponse you get access to the QueryString property
 var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
 var oauthVerifier = response.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];

//The response stream contains the HTTP response body, 
//which will not contain the URL to which the redirect is sent
//I'm not sure if there is anything there that you will need
var responseBody = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

 //AUTHORIZE WITH CREDENTIALS FROM USER.  -- Not sure what this section is doing
 var queryString = string.Format("oauth_token={0}", oauthVerifier);
 var authorizeUrl = "https://api.projectplace.com/authorize?" + queryString;
 Process.Start(authorizeUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have modified the question above with some example code. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your effort to help me. One thing that confused me is you have tried to use QueryString before authorization. Only after the Process.Start(authorizeUrl); is executed will it redirect, adding the oauth_verifier parameter. If i try to use the code you've given above, after the Process.Start(authorizeUrl); it throws an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Just to clarify what I put in my code example above. The code after //TRY AND READ VERIFICATION STRING AFTER AUTHORIZATION REDIRECT is where I think I need to get the oauth_verifier parameter back. Basically, the Process.Start(authorizeUrl); sends me to a login screen where I have a break in the code to enter the username and password before I step to the next code to try and read the oauth_verifier parameter, which I can see after I have entered the username and password.